# crypto js des decryption breaks when string has salt

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptojs

Crypto js is not able to decrypt the encoded string. Whereas in one online platform I can see it is able to decode

[image]

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var key = "peekaboo";
var ciphertext = "gI3f92FdqXl0ZYDHYpGEdD2tjpfJzXgfWQxFc+e0G2Xf+w8KfyNnvBuXBpgRpqpMTpxs18nBdsU=";
ciphertext     = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(ciphertext);

var bytes  = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(ciphertext, key);

var originalText = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
 
console.log(originalText, "ORIGINAL TEXT"); // 'my
```

> output is empty

Comment: The ciphertext is not a regular string but a **Base64 encoded** string. Use a converter from CryptoJs to get the bytes from it.

Comment: could you post an example as to how @MichaelFehr

Comment: For CryptoJs there is a good documentation available: https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/. First you should find out how the DES encryption is done - what mode is in use, is the value in ciphertext just the encrypted data or is there an initialization vector prepended ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not able to decrypt the encryptedValue using crypto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65218526/not-able-to-decrypt-the-encryptedvalue-using-crypto)

Comment: The initialization vector prepended and i decoded the base64 still it remains same @MichaelFehr

Comment: If there is an IV prepended you need to cut it of the complete ciphertext and feed it to the decryption function. As well, you need to know what DEC **mode** was in used to encrypt. In the image you provided I can clearly see that the decryption (not "decoding") does not work well because the website (you didn't mention) decrypts to some garbage at the beginning of the decrypted text - this is a clear sign that **this** website isn't using the same mode of operation.

Comment: Sorry but the code in your other linked question is in VB and not Java - not my programming framework.