# Not able to decrypt the encryptedValue using crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, vb.net, cryptojs

I am trying to decrypt a value (encrypted in des) coming from VB.
When I try to decrypt the encryptedValue using crypto in Javascript the output gives me an empty value.
I have attached how the encryption was done in VB.

**HOW I AM TRYING TO DECRYPT IN JAVASCRIPT**

```
var CryptoJS       = require("crypto-js");
var key            = "peekaboo";
var encryptedValue = "50AznWWn4fJI19T392wIv/ZysP/Ke3mB";
encryptedValue     = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(encryptedValue);

var data           = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(encryptedValue, key, { iv: "cbauthiv" });

const email  = data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(email, "ORIGINAL TEXT");
```

[image]

**THE WAY IT IS ENCRYPTED IN VB**

```
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Text
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Private Const ENCRYPTIONKEY As String = "peekaboo"

    Sub Main()

       
        Dim s As String = Encrypt("ditzymoose@outlook.com")

        Dim r As String = Decrypt(s)
        Console.ReadLine()


    End Sub


    Private Function Encrypt(stringToEncrypt As String) As String
        Dim rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim byteArray() As Byte = New Byte(8) {}
        Dim iv_value As String = "cbauthiv"
        Dim key() As Byte = {}
        Dim IV() As Byte = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(iv_value, 8))

        key = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Left(ENCRYPTIONKEY, 8))
        Dim des As New DESCryptoServiceProvider
        rng.GetBytes(byteArray)
        Dim Salt As String = BitConverter.ToString(byteArray)
        Dim SaltedInput As String = Salt & "~" & stringToEncrypt
        Dim inputByteArray() As Byte = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToEncrypt)
        Dim ms As New MemoryStream
        Dim cs As New CryptoStream(ms, des.CreateEncryptor(key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        cs.Write(inputByteArray, 0, inputByteArray.Length)
        cs.FlushFinalBlock()
        Return Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())

    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: I suppose you at least should decode from base64 before decrypting. See https://gist.github.com/ufologist/5581486

Comment: still same  , check new edit
@Anatoly

Comment: That's not a Java but VB encryption in your example

Comment: Yes that's a typo @ Michael Fehr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key and IV must be passed as `WordArray`. For the conversion the Utf8-Encoder has to be used, [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#encoders).

Also, the ciphertext must be passed as a `CipherParams` object or alternatively Base64 encoded (which is then implicitly converted to a `CipherParams` object), [here](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

With these changes the ciphertext of the VB code can be successfully decrypted using the CryptoJS code:

```js
var key            = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("peekaboo");
var iv             = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse("cbauthiv");
var encryptedValue = "50AznWWn4fJI19T392wIv/ZysP/Ke3mB";

var data           = CryptoJS.DES.decrypt(encryptedValue, key, {iv: iv});
var email          = data.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);

console.log(email, "ORIGINAL TEXT");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/crypto-js/4.0.0/crypto-js.min.js"></script>
```

Please note that DES is insecure ([here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/74)) and was replaced by AES almost 20 years ago. Also insecure is a static IV. Instead, a random IV should be generated for each encryption.
Furthermore a password should not be used as key. If a password is to be used, the key should be derived from the password using a reliable key derivation function such as PBKDF2.

Comment: also if this contains a salt how do we decrypt it, as in crypto I couldn't find the method to accommodate the salt @Topaco

Comment: @art - A salt is usually applied when encryption is done with a password: A _random_ salt is generated for _each_ encryption. A key derivation function (e.g. PBKDF2) is used to derive a key (and IV) from the (random) salt and password. The (non-secret) salt is sent to the recipient along with the ciphertext. Concerning your comment: During decryption salt and ciphertext would have to be separated. With the salt and the password, the recipient can reconstruct the key and IV and perform the decryption.

Comment: @art - But this logic is not implemented in the VB code for encryption. In the VB code a random salt is generated and concatenated with the plaintext. Here the concatenation with the plaintext is pointless. Instead, as already mentioned, salt and ciphertext would have to be concatenated. Apart from that the concatenated result is not used at all.